# Color transformation: RBG 565 blend between two colors

Tags: colors, arduino

Given are:

1. Foreground color in RGB 565 format
2. Background color in RGB 565 format
3. 1 byte Grayscale value, where 00 means transparent and FF means black

Goal:

To figure out the math so that the resulting RGB 565 value is:

1. Background color if Grayscale value is 00
2. Foreground color if Grayscale value is FF
3. Proportionally in-between for other Grayscale values

Background:

This is for a microcomputer board with a TFT display, to display cursive fonts.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is your question? how to blend colours is covered by many resources online. all you have to do is search the web for "blend rgb"

Comment: @Piglet Great suggestion, thank you!